# Make tkinter prompt inherit parent window's icon

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program using tkinter, and have successfully managed to use a colour icon for my program using code that looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, '-default', 'iconfile.ico')
```

However, when I create a simple dialog, it has the default tkinter icon. I have tried setting the parent to my main window, but the icon is still the default one.

How could the icon be set to not be the default one?

Comment: By `dialog` do you mean a window created by `filedialog`?

Comment: @Lafexlos I mean tkinter.simpledialog (python 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got an answer from a user on another site:

It's not a configurable option in the class. You'll need to make a subclass which sets the icon:

```
class StringDialog(simpledialog._QueryString):
    def body(self, master):
        super().body(master)
        self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

    def ask_string(title, prompt, **kargs):
        d = StringDialog(title, prompt, **kargs)
        return d.result
```

You'll also need to subclass _QueryFloat and _QueryInteger if you want those versions. (These classes are supposed to be private, so you might have to fix this in future updates.)